# Form Accessibility for dynamic list of requirements

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility

So I have a form that dynamically will update a list of requirements.  Those requirements are always there as a list but as you type it should update the list with checks and color changing. I need to make this code complaint with accessibility standards to I added a few rolls dynamically. I won't include the whole HTML here but just the list which is in a `role=alert` unordered list. Is this the proper way to set something like this up?

Here is the invalid/waiting element

```
<li class="rule-waiting" id="capital" role=""></li>
```

Here is when the password meets the requirement

```
<li class="rule-passed" id="special" role="presentation"></li>
```

This code example isn't dynamic, you have to press the button to validate but it works as a simple example of what I am trying to achieve:
http://codepen.io/mfeola/pen/mVbYZL

Comment: The right attribute is `role`, not `roll`

Comment: sorry that was just in my description, i will fix it

Answer (score 1):

What is important is more to alert about errors, than informing of success. Your implementation won't work as the `role=alert` will be read after the page has loaded.

You should look at the `aria-live` property which will let you dynamically inform of modifications. 
[ARIA19: Using ARIA role=alert or Live Regions to Identify Errors](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/ARIA19.html)

In your case, I would say that the visual effect is good, (the use of `aria-describedby` is a very good thing), but it would be a better choice to use a red cross to inform about errors.

Maybe the `live-region` or the `role=alert` should be in another element to inform only about those errors.

Of course, you would have to test it using different screenreaders as the implementation differs.